# How to pass variables to Expression Func Projection before compile

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write Expression Functions for my projections. I found a good article about that [link](https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/). But I couldn't figure out how can I pass variables to these functions.

How can I write a projection function for this one

```cs
int i = 3;
var query = await _db.Users
                .FilterByName(name)
                .Select(item => new SearchResultItemViewModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Article = item.FirstName + i.ToString()
                });
}))
```

---

This one is working. In select SQL string has only Id and Firstname but I can't pass any variable.

```cs
   var query = await _db.Users
                .FilterByName(name)
                .Select(item => SearchResultItemViewModel.Projection)
```

```cs
public static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, SearchResultItemViewModel>> Projection
        {
            get
            {
                return item => new SearchResultItemViewModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Article = item.FirstName
                };
            }
        }
```

---

This one is working only if you call compile and invoke. SQL string has all rows. Leading to bad performance

```cs
   var query = await _db.Users
                .FilterByName(name)
                .Select(item => SearchResultItemViewModel.Projection.Compile().Invoke(item,i))
```

```cs
public static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser,int, SearchResultItemViewModel>> Projection
        {
            get
            {
                return( item,i) => new SearchResultItemViewModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Article = item.FirstName + i.ToString()
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: The example on referenced page shows that if you use  [ReplaceWithExpression(PropertyName = nameof(Projection))]
of course with referenced library. You can achive the only properties you wanted.

Comment: I tried the Author's library. It still fetches all rows.

Comment: On my phone so hard to explain. Change the projection from a property to a method (get rid of the get), pass in the parameter and then reference the projection in the select call without the "item" lambda. Eg. .Select(SearchResultItemViewModel.Projection(myparam)). Also test that SQL projections are working with the library without a parameter before attempting this.

Comment: It's worked! Great! Thank you @BenCull
```.Select(SearchResultItemViewModel.Projection(i))```
------
```public static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, SearchResultItemViewModel>> Projection(int a)
        {

            return item => new SearchResultItemViewModel
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Article = item.FirstName + a.ToString()
            };

        }```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use EF so this might vary in your specific use case, but this seems to be a question about LINQ Expressions more than anything else.

The first big problem is that you are trying to use an `Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, int, SearchResultItemViewModel>>` where you really meant `Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, SearchResultItemViewModel>>` and that's not going to do what you want.  Instead of binding to a variable you're invoking the [indexed variant of `Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.select).  So instead of getting the same value of `i` for all rows you get the index of the row.

When you create an expression that references a variable, one of two things happens.  For local variables (and parameters) the value is copied to an anonymous class instance which is bound to the expression, so you can't change it afterwards.  For other variables the expression contains a reference to the variable itself, as well as the containing object for non-static variables.

Which means that you could in principle use a static variable to alter the parameter and never have to recreate the projection expression.  There are certainly times when this is useful.

On the other hand, your code above is creating a new instance each time you access the `Projection` property.  So why not just change it to a function and generate the expression you need when you need it?

```
public static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, SearchResultItemViewModel>> Projection(int parm)
    => item => new SearchResultItemViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Article = item.FirstName + parm.ToString()
        };
```

Each time you invoke the method you'll get back an expression that uses the specified value.

Or you could use an expression visitor to take a template expression and modify the constants in it to whatever you need at the time.  Fun, but a bit beyond scope here I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I convert Expression function to your example code, the return type is changing to Expression Func instead of SearchResultItemViewModel. If I want to get SearchResultItemViewModel I have to call compile&invoke which is the same as my last code example.
```List<Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, SearchResultItemViewModel>>> query =...```

Comment: This should work in theory. I wonder if projections with the index are supported (in the library).

Comment: Apology for my answer @Corey I wrote your sample code by mistaken with get statement. You code working pretty well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BenCull Select projections with index in LinqToSQL seem to produce the index values during enumeration, after the data has been returned from the server.  I haven't explored this extensively however, and don't have experience with EF to test there.